# solving a trig derivative

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to work this trig derivative but i'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

I've edited:

$$
\begin{align}
y &= u(a\cos u + b\cot u)\\ \\
y' &=(u)(-a\sin u - b\csc^2 u)+ (a\cos u +b\cot u)(1)\\
&= -au\sin u - bu\csc^2 u + a\cos u + b\cot u\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The derivative of $u$ with respect to $u$ is not $0$. Also, where did $c$ come from in the last line?

Comment: sorry the c was an error shouldn't be there. i've also updated it

Comment: Unless you are being asked to use trig identities to rewrite into another form, what you have now is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that $y$ is a function of $u$, (in other words, you're computing $\frac{dy}{du})$, then $$\frac{d}{du}(u) = 1\neq 0$$

So you cannot drop the right-hand side of the application of the product rule.

I'm also puzzled how/why you introduced the constant $c$ in your move to the final line of your work. Typo?

**Re: your edit(s).** Your answer is now correct.

But note that you can stop at the the second line $y' = \cdots$, in which you applied the product rule to differentiate $y$. Of course, you'd want to simply drop the factor of $1$ on the right term of your derivative.

After calculating the derivative, you seem to have distributed $u$ over the left term, but then in the next line, you factored out $u$ (which you had just distributed), ending precisely where you were to start with: the expression immediately following $y'$.

Comment: oh ok haha. thanks for clearing that up :)

Comment: You're welcome! Nice work.